# authblk footnote marks before/atop commas

Tags: footnotes, punctuation, titles, authblk

The `authblk` package, in footnoted mode, puts footnote marks inside commas ("Alice<sup>1</sup>,") which is bad typography.  Is there any way to persuade it to put the footnote marks outside the commas ("Alice,<sup>1</sup>"), or even better, on top of them?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\begin{document}
\title{A Demonstration of Bad Punctuation Placement}
\author[1]{Alice}
\author[2]{Bob}
\author[3]{Peggy}
\author[4]{Trent}
\affil[1]{}\affil[2]{}\affil[3]{}\affil[4]{}
\date{}
\maketitle

Better: $\mbox{Alice,}^1$ $\mbox{Bob,}^2$ $\mbox{Peggy,}^3$
and $\mbox{Trent}^4$

Even better: $\mbox{Alice\rlap{,}}^1$ $\mbox{Bob\rlap{,}}^2$
$\mbox{Peggy\rlap{,}}^3$ and $\mbox{Trent}^4$

\end{document}
```

(Ignore everything but the "Alice, Bob, Peggy, Trent" lines.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is actually easier to obtain the "even better" output, if you're willing to accept some spacing adjustments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}% http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\rlap{\textsuperscript{\normalfont#1}}}
\renewcommand\Authsep{,~\,}
\renewcommand\Authands{,~\,and }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{A Demonstration of Bad Punctuation Placement}
\author[1]{Alice}
\author[2]{Bob}
\author[3]{Peggy}
\author[4]{Trent}
\affil[1]{}\affil[2]{}\affil[3]{}\affil[4]{}
\date{}
\maketitle

Better: $\mbox{Alice,}^1$ $\mbox{Bob,}^2$ $\mbox{Peggy,}^3$
and $\mbox{Trent}^4$

Even better: $\mbox{Alice\rlap{,}}^1$ $\mbox{Bob\rlap{,}}^2$
$\mbox{Peggy\rlap{,}}^3$ and $\mbox{Trent}^4$

\end{document}
```

The `\AB@authnote` is first set, followed by `\Authsep` or `\Authands`, depending on whether you're the last author or not. The renewal of `\AB@authnote` to now have a right overlap (`\rlap`) causes the authors to be a little too condensed, which is corrected using a `,~\,` and/or `,~\,and` spacing.

Comment: This didn't quite work, because the author list in my actual document is very long, so I need TeX to be able to break the line after one of the commas.  Changing `,~\,` to `,\hskip 5.5pt\relax` in both places did the trick (monkeyed with the width until it looked good).  I also added a tiny kern inside the `\AB@authnote` because the superscripts were colliding with the letters.  Anyway, thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: @Zack: True, `~` is not breakable. You could also use `,\,\ ` (ending with a control space). Also, the solution is not 100% perfect, since the font kerning in "even better" differs ever so slightly from the output provided by my solution, but it is negligible.