# authblk package improvements

Tags: spacing, titles, authblk

A simple way to write articles with authors and affiliations is by using the package `authblk`; however, it looks a bit obsolete, and lacking some desirable (for me at least) functions, e.g.:

- the footnote thing for author's affiliation is badly implemented, as `name\footnote,` is worse than `name,\footnote`, namely the footnote should be placed *before* the comma
- the affiliation command should allow me to break with `\\` where I prefer, not just put a comma
- there should be a command to easily put preprint number, eg in the top right corner and flushed-right, as well as a hyperlink footnote with author's email

Do you see a way to implement it, as a package and not by inserting commands in one's own tex file? Should one contact the original author?

The minimal example is

```
\usepackage{authblk}

\renewcommand\Affilfont{\it \small}

\author[*]{one}
\author[**]{two}

\affil[*]{one line\authorcr another line}
\affil[**]{other line}
```

this produces the wrong spacing mentioned at point 1, while `\authorcr` restores the font to the one used for author, so it is not good here.
The last point should be ideally a command like `\email[*]{address at dot}` with authomatic hyperlink and `\preprint{some number}` which is displayed top flushed right (I understand it is possible to use `fancyhdr`, but it sounds more involved)

Comment: I don't think Patrick Daly is actively developing his packages other than dealing with the occasional bug. So I suspect that asking him for feature requests will not be useful. Your point 1 is not clear. Minimal example? On point 2, there is a command `\\authorcr` which allows breaks. On point 3 you could do this easily with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Still not clear. Why are you using `\footnote`?  Can you actually add a minimal document to show what the problem is?

Comment: @AlanMunn - In case of `preprint` bundle (`authblk` is part of it), the situation is that they are provided "as is".  I'm afraid that even bugs will not be fixed.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B there are putex.sty or hepth.sty that have some of the properties I mentioned, but e.g. not the second point

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/authblk-footnote-marks-before-atop-commas